# AWS Role creation via Cloudformation error with LimitExceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to build a CodeBuild template in Cloudformation. I need to add a role to allow it to perform the need action. I create the following role (rules found thanks to the AWS documentation):

```
 "CodeBuildServiceRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Action": [
                            "codebuild:*",
                            "codecommit:GetBranch",
                            "codecommit:GetCommit",
                            "codecommit:GetRepository",
                            "codecommit:ListBranches",
                            "codecommit:ListRepositories",
                            "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                            "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                            "ecr:ListImages",
                            "elasticfilesystem:DescribeFileSystems",
                            "events:DeleteRule",
                            "events:DescribeRule",
                            "events:DisableRule",
                            "events:EnableRule",
                            "events:ListTargetsByRule",
                            "events:ListRuleNamesByTarget",
                            "events:PutRule",
                            "events:PutTargets",
                            "events:RemoveTargets",
                            "logs:GetLogEvents",
                            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                        ],
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Resource": "*"
                    },
                    {
                        "Action": [
                            "logs:DeleteLogGroup"
                        ],
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/codebuild/*:log-stream:*"
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "ssm:PutParameter"
                        ],
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/CodeBuild/*"
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "ssm:StartSession"
                        ],
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:ecs:*:*:task/*/*"
                    }, ....
                ]
            }
        }
```

(Note that StackOverflow does not allow me to put the whole role here there are actually 7 other statement with 3 or 4 actions)

But when running the CF stack, I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot exceed quota for ACLSizePerRole: 2048 (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 409; Error Code: LimitExceeded;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your policy is in the wrong place. You are trying to specify all this stuff as part of the `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` which is the place to store the configuration who is allowed to assume the role, **not** the place to store what the role is allowed to do.

To specify what the role is allowed to do use dedicated policies, and then specify them e.g. within the [`Policies`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-policies) property. Note that such policies also have length restrictions. You can work around that by splitting one large policy into multiple policies, but there is a limit on the number of policies as well. At some point you would need to reconsider how you are granting permissions and would need to optimize your statements.